# iOS9 Contacts Framework missing phone number labels?

Tags: ios, xcode, contacts

I am implementing a new iOS application that is only supporting iOS9+. Thus we are using the new contacts framework to access phone numbers for contacts stored on the device.

CNPhoneNumber defines the labels for different types of phone numbers, but it contains a much smaller list of types than the actual iOS contacts screen. For example on my iPhone I am able to add a number off the type "Work" to a contact but there is no corresponding CNLabelPhoneNumberWork label in the SDK. Am I looking in the wrong place or is this just the way it is? Contacts may have a bunch of numbers that I am unable to identify unless I hardcode Apple's "*$!!$*" string to my app?

As far as I can tell CNPhoneNumber only provides these labels:

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
public let CNLabelPhoneNumberiPhone: String
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
public let CNLabelPhoneNumberMobile: String
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
public let CNLabelPhoneNumberMain: String
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
public let CNLabelPhoneNumberHomeFax: String
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
public let CNLabelPhoneNumberWorkFax: String
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
public let CNLabelPhoneNumberOtherFax: String
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
public let CNLabelPhoneNumberPager: String
```

When I go and add numbers to my contacts the list of available types is much longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in the sense that these should be the only predefined ones for phone number labels.

But, as described in Apple's doc: Phone Number Labels

> These constants are predefined labels that **can** be used in a `CNLabeledValue` object having a `CNPhoneNumber` value.

You would still get a `NSString*` (note **not** `enum`) from `CNLabeledValue` `label` property, and it would contain whatever appears in the Contacts. So be prepared you might also get odd input user created by "Custom Labels" option.

---

For the question of "Contacts may have a bunch of numbers that I am unable to identify unless I hardcode Apple's "$!!$" string to my app?"

The answer would be **NO**

`phoneNumbers` of a `CNContact`:

> This property is an array of `CNLabeledValue` objects, each of which has a label and a `CNPhoneNumber` value.

When you iterate though it, `.label` would give you something like 'Work', and `.value` would give the actual number you want.

**EDIT:**

Interestingly, in [Contacts Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/), there appears `CNLabelHome` and `CNLabelWork`, which appears to be "Generic Labels" constants in `CNLabeledValue` Class.

Comment: My problem is that the .label property of CNLabeledValue is actually giving me strings that look like some kind of identifiers that need to be mapped. So with my code like this:

func mapData(number: CNLabeledValue?) {
        if let valueObj = number?.value as? CNPhoneNumber {
            numberLabel.text = "\(valueObj.stringValue)"
        }
        CNLabelPhoneNumberWorkFax
        
        numberTitleLabel.text = number?.label
    }

The numberTitleLabel ends up being a string like _$! Mobile !$_

Comment: try `localizedStringForLabel(_:)` method?

Comment: You were on the right track with the non-phone number labels. So CNLabelWork can be used for the 'Work' type phone number.